# Only one if/else statement executing

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have two if/else statements comparing the same variable, with in one function. I do not desire, nor see a reason to nest the statements.

```
function checkUser() {
  var user = document.getElementById('usern').value;
  var element = document.getElementById('labelUser');

  if (user.length < 3 || user.length > 15) {
    element.innerHTML = "Invalid length.";
    element.style.color = "red";

  } 
  else {
    element.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.zrfunding.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CheckMarkSmallGreen.jpg" alt="Valid" height="35" width="30"/>';  
  }   

  if (user.match(/[\<\>!@#\$%^&\*,]+/i)){ 
    element.innerHTML = "Invalid characters.";
    element.style.color = "red";

  }   
  else {
    element.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.zrfunding.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CheckMarkSmallGreen.jpg" alt="Valid" height="35" width="30"/>';  
  }     

}
```

How could this code be improved?

Comment: umm this doesnt really belong here better move it to code review - codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Should be migrated to codereview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkUser() {
  var user = document.getElementById('usern').value;
  var element = document.getElementById('labelUser');

  if (user.length < 3 || user.length > 15) {
    element.innerHTML = "Invalid length.";
    element.style.color = "red";

  } 
  else if (user.match(/[\<\>!@#\$%^&\*,]+/i)){ 
    element.innerHTML = "Invalid characters.";
    element.style.color = "red";

  }   
  else {
    element.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.zrfunding.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CheckMarkSmallGreen.jpg" alt="Valid" height="35" width="30"/>';  
  }     
}
```

Comment: It worked great, thanks. I suppose the first time I put "else if" to see if it would work, I must have done something else wrong in the script at the time. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: You do realize you're skipping a layer of error checking by using an else if in there, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize the code like this:

```
  var gotoElse = false;
  if (user.length < 3 || user.length > 15) {
    element.innerHTML = "Invalid length.";
    element.style.color = "red";

  } 
  else gotoElse = true; 

  if (user.match(/[\<\>!@#\$%^&\*,]+/i)){ 
    element.innerHTML = "Invalid characters.";
    element.style.color = "red";

  }   
  else gotoElse = true;

  if(gotoElse) {
    element.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.zrfunding.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CheckMarkSmallGreen.jpg" alt="Valid" height="35" width="30"/>';  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `else if`:

```
  if (user.length < 3 || user.length > 15) {
    element.innerHTML = "Invalid length.";
    element.style.color = "red";

  } 
  else if (user.match(/[\<\>!@#\$%^&\*,]+/i)){ 
    element.innerHTML = "Invalid characters.";
    element.style.color = "red";
  }   
  else {
    element.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.zrfunding.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CheckMarkSmallGreen.jpg" alt="Valid" height="35" width="30"/>';  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter way of writing it.

```
var valid = '<img src="http://www.zrfunding.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CheckMarkSmallGreen.jpg" alt="Valid" height="35" width="30"/>';

element.innerHTML = user.length < 3 || user.length > 15 ? "Invalid length." : valid;
element.innerHTML = user.match(/[\<\>!@#\$%^&\*,]+/i) ? "Invalid characters." : valid;

if( element.innerHTML !== valid ){
  element.style.color = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the problem around... first assign the default values to a variable and overwrite only when necessary.  Then use those variables to assign to the element at the end.

```
function checkUser() {
  var user = document.getElementById('usern').value;
  var element = document.getElementById('labelUser');
  var outputHTML = '<img src="http://www.zrfunding.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CheckMarkSmallGreen.jpg" alt="Valid" height="35" width="30"/>';
  var color = '';

  if (user.length < 3 || user.length > 15) {
    outputHTML = "Invalid length.";
    color = "red";
  } 

  if (user.match(/[\<\>!@#\$%^&\*,]+/i)){ 
    outputHTML = "Invalid characters.";
    color = "red";
  }   

  element.innerHTML = outputHTML;
  element.style.color = color;   
}
```

Comment: I like that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a very nice output that will display both errors if they are both present

```
function checkUser() {
  var user = document.getElementById('usern').value;
  var element = document.getElementById('labelUser');
  var errorMsg = [];

  if (user.length < 3 || user.length > 15) {
    errorMsg.push("Invalid length"); 
  } 

  if (user.match(/[\<\>!@#\$%^&\*\s,]+/i)){ 
    errorMsg.push("Invalid characters");
  }   

  if (errorMsg.length) {
    element.innerHTML = errorMsg.join(",");
    element.style.color = "red"; 
  } else {
    element.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.zrfunding.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CheckMarkSmallGreen.jpg" alt="Valid" height="35" width="30"/>'; 
  }
}
```

you can find the running sample here, http://jsfiddle.net/LR9u3/

Comment: I updated it a bit to eliminate a var and eliminate spaces since you don't typically see those in user names, http://jsfiddle.net/LR9u3/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkUser() {
    var user = document.getElementById('usern').value,
        element = document.getElementById('labelUser'),
        err = [],
        html, color;

    if (user.length < 3 || user.length > 15) {
        err.push('Invalid length');
    }
    if (user.match(/[\<\>!@#\$%^&\*,]+/i)) {
        err.push('Invalid characters');
    }
    if (err.length) {
        color = 'red';
        html = err.join('<br />');
    } else {
        html = '<img src="http://www.zrfunding.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CheckMarkSmallGreen.jpg" alt="Valid" height="35" width="30"/>';
    }
    element.style.color = color || '';
    element.innerHTML = html;
}
```